# InputStream with "events" in Java

Tags: java

I have a situation in Java where I have a method that returns an InputStream, and I want to make it so that whenever the person calls the close function on that InputStream, some other place in the code gets notified (like a callback).

However, the actual InputStream I'm returning is a sub-class of InputStream returned by a library call, so I don't have direct control over it.

My current solution is to create a subclass of InputStream, which has an InputStream member variable which is instantiated by the library call in the constructor, and I just override the methods of InputStream and just have them use the variable's methods, with the addition that the close() function does something extra.

This works, but I would like to reduce the overhead of having to create a whole new class, override all the necessary methods, just so that I can do a single event when close() is called.

Answer (score 4):

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) has a variety of filtering I/O streams that make it much easier to do what you describe.

Comment: I found AutoCloseInputStream in that library which is great for what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much have to do it this way if you want it to be transparent to the user of the InputStream.  that said, you don't need to write all that code yourself as FilterInputStream does all the basic work for you (you would just need to override the `close()` method).

Comment: Mixing this with @bmarguiles answer, [`org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/ProxyInputStream.html) is an extension of `FilterInputStream`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Java bean event mechanism to do that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/events.html

This assumes that the listeners and broadcaster are running in the same JVM.

Here's what I had in mind:

```
package io;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * BroadcastingInputStream broadcasts to interested listeners when it closes.
 * @author Michael
 * @since 10/31/12 8:34 PM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169206/possible-in-java-to-create-an-event-when-a-function-is-called-on-a-particular-ob/13169271#comment17920062_13169271
 */
public class BroadcastingInputStream extends InputStream {

    private InputStream is;
    private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;

    public BroadcastingInputStream(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
        this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return this.is.read();
    }

    public void addCloseListener(PropertyChangeListener closeListener) {
        this.propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(closeListener);
    }

    public void removeCloseListener(PropertyChangeListener closeListener) {
        this.propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(closeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
        this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("closed", false, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.  He wants to avoid creating this whole subclass of InputStream and doing pass-throughs on all the methods.  OP, sorry, don't see an easier way.  At least there are only 7 or so methods...

Comment: I guess I did misunderstand.  I'll delete.

Comment: also this will be a garbage input stream that will only read per byte